# Script em PHP para impedir que dois dados iguais sejam cadastrados(MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para a biblioteca da minha escola e gostaria de saber como fazer um script em PHP, com banco MySQL, que, na hora do cadastro, verifique se não há um registro com aquele CPF.

Comment: Mais fácil e seguro colocar o campo do `CPF` como `UNIQUE`, dessa forma o banco não irá permitir valores repetido e irá retornar um erro ao tentar.

Comment: Certo, mas como eu posso personalizar esse erro, tipo; "Esse CPF já foi cadastrado."

Comment: Esses erros possuem um `código` e uma `mensagem` padrão. Você pode forçar o erro e pegar o `código` retornado, tendo ele, basta fazer uma validação para quando o erro tiver esse `código`, retornar a mensagem desejada.

Comment: Entendi, mas você pode me dar um exemplo(com código)?

Comment: Mais tarde eu posto, não estou com tempo de fazer o código. Você está usando `MySQLi` ou `PDO` ?